# How to get domain in middleware, then pass it to components/store before axios calls [Nuxt]

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I want to access the domain name before any `axios` calls are made. Because the `axios` calls need the domain URL to make them.

So, I want to get the domain first, then pass it to the store/components so they can load properly.

My understanding is that the domain is held in the `req` object of the context which is passed to the midddleware.

How would I get it and then pass it to the store and the components?

Comment: If you configure the [`baseURL`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig) at build time, you shouldn't need the domain name when using `axios`.

Comment: I want to dynamically set the baseURL, as I want to have multiple domains pointing to the same frontend code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. Use `nuxtServerInit`. This function is called on the serverside, and only once if you reload the page. For this you need to go to your store and add this:

//store

```
actions: {
   nuxtServerInit(store, context){
      store.commit("setUrl", context.req.originalUrl);
   }
}
```

Well thats all. People also like to destructure the arguments:

```
actions: {
   nuxtServerInit({ commit},{req}){
      commit("setUrl", req.originalUrl);
   } 
}
```

I am not sure if its `originalUrl` or just `url`... or maybe something different.

Comment: I found it on `context.req.headers.host`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on lfaruki's answer, you can do it that way. Here is my solution:

**store/index.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    domain: '',
});

export const mutations = {
    setDomain(state, domain) {
        state.domain = domain;
    },
};

export const actions = {
    nuxtServerInit(store, context) {
        store.commit('setDomain', context.req.headers.host);
    },
};

export const getters = {
    domain: (state) => state.domain,
};
```

**middleware/domain.js**

```
export default function ({ route, store, redirect }) {
    console.log('hey look at that', store.getters['domain']);
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
    ...

    router: {
        middleware: 'domain'
    },
}
```